# Wrong component is being rendered using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

when I´m trying to navigate to the folowing url http://localhost:3000/alunos/adicionar-aluno but it renders the component {Detail Student} with empty values instead of the proper component { FormAddStudent }.
I´m new to react so not sure what I´m doing wrong, I´m trying to use the exact prop but without success.

Here is the code:

```
  <Router>
  <CssBaseline />
  <div className="App" className={classes.root}>
    <Header />
    <MenuContainer />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact />
      <Route path="/alunos" exact component = { ListStudents }/>
      <Route path="/contratos" exact component = { ListContracts }/>
      <Route path="/turmas" exact component = { ListClasses }/>
      <Route path="/estagios" exact component = { ListInterships }/>
      <Route path="/formadores" exact component = { ListInstructors }/>
      <Route path="/analise-seguros" exact component = { ListInsurances }/>
      <Route path="/alunos/:id" component = { DetailStudent }/>
      <Route path="/alunos/adicionar-aluno"  exact component = { FormAddStudent }/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you rearrange the lines so that `/alunos/adicionar-aluno` will come before `/alunos/:id`? That should fix it.

Comment: remove the space between 'component' prop and '=' sign and curly braces

Comment: Thanks. @HalilC that solved the issue, now I understand why it was not working. The pattern was being picked up first by the rout /alunos/ because it has the same "part" of the url so that was being rendered. Thanks m8

Answer (score 3):

React Router starts from the top and look for the first matching route. **exact** prop does not stop React router from rendering all matching routes ,it only ensures one matcing route is rendered.In your case you have two matching routes:

- /alunos/:id
- /alunos/adicionar-aluno

It first catches /alunos/:id and renders component associated for that route.So the **order** of the routes is important in this case.As @HalilC mentioned in comments,switching the order of routes will solve your problem.